# Want to replace bookmark text or title using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Want to replace bookmark text or title using itextsharp.

My pdf already contains bookmark upto 3 levels.

In each level I want to remove space from the end of line.

For examples
"Table of Content " to be replaced with "Table of Content"
"Introduction " to "Introduction"

Like this

Comment: Any help will help me to achieve this goal

Comment: What have you tried so far, what speed you?

Comment: Till now I manage to read the bookmark Title including child bookmark and also able to replace the Title as per my requirement, but when the pdf is generate there is no changes in bookmark

Comment: If you showed show the pivotal code of your attempt to manipulate the bookmarks, we could better help you along.